# Help in writing REGEX

Tags: java, regex

I have to take user input from a HTML form in this format (field1)(space)(field2) where both field1 and field2 are Strings but the restrictions are:

- field1 & field2 can't be integers
- they must be alphanumeric
- they should not start with the same character

Note that this pattern can repeat itself, eg:
`abc def ghi jkl`

Comment: Huh? I don't understand your explanation, but why must you use regexp?

Comment: What you want is impossible. "Maybe not be a space" means there will be no way to decide where field1 ends and field2 starts. As well, can't be integer, can't be alphanumeric... so non-printable characters only? Entering tabs and carriage returns into a text field is such fun...

Comment: Regex will match patterns but I don't think it'll do much comparing or maybe not in as much detail as you'd like to go in to.

Comment: If there's no space in between them how would you be able to identify where one ends and the other begins?

Comment: @ Marc: I need user to enter a book title so if he enters (JSP @#$) or (@@@!!! 123)  i want this to be invalid....so plz tell me if there is another way....

Comment: And what do you mean by "......and this format can continue....."?

Comment: @alexcoco : if there is no space than its easy i will do field.matches("[a-zA-Z]+$")....actually i want if there is space between them its not included in the above mentioned regex....

Comment: @ Aleadam  it means abc def ghi.....

Comment: Why can't a valid book title contain '@'? Why can't a book title contain digits?

Comment: @Kaj I think it can contain digits but cannot be only digits. But I agree, why not let them be digits?

Comment: kk let them be digits.....but than also how to avoid the space between the two field to be included into regex...

Comment: If you're going to be processing this information in the back end anyways why not just match them with RegEx and use your (Java?) back end to make sure the values are unique? But what if you have two titles that begin with "The"? Does that make them invalid? I don't understand why you have such strange restrictions on a title that can be anything.

Comment: i think i found the way.... split the string into string array using split() than check them against regex independently....

Comment: @RanRag Yes, you will definitely need something more than RegEx to check anything other than patterns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> field1 & field2 can't be integers

```
(?!\p{Digit}+\b)
```

> they must be alphanumeric

and presumably non-empty

```
\p{Alnum}+
```

> they should not start with the same character

requires capturing the first character in a capturing group so the above becomes

```
(\p{Alnum})\p{Alnum}*
```

and you need a negative lookahead

```
(?!\1)
```

Putting it all together and allowing separating you can use the following

```
Pattern.compile("^\\s*(?:(?!\\p{Digit}+\\b)(?!\1)(\\p{Alnum})\\p{Alnum}*\\s*)+\\Z");
```